# Fastest Way to do block operations on an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, block

What's the most efficient way to process the image into overlapping blocks of multiple sizes?

I checked nlfilter, blockproc on MATLAB, they are taking long time to execute.

Comment: Do you want to split the image into separate blocks, or process the image block-by-block ? If the former edit your question to clarify, if the latter, I suspect you'll find it difficult to beat the performance of the Matlab in-built functions so long as you choose the right ones.  Sometimes complex processing over large data structures takes a long time.

Answer (score -1):

The Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox will allow you to do processing on the GPU:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/discovery/matlab-gpu.html

I've not used this myself, but it should be fast particularly if you are using commands which are GPU-enabled.